# ScalaMock 3. Mocking methods with function parameter

Tags: scala, mocking, playframework-2.1, scala-2.10

I would like to mock methods with a function parameter and a function parameter in combination with curried paramters like:

```
trait Secured {

  def IsAuthenticated(f: AuthenticatedData => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
    // auth code
    f(AuthenticatedData.create(request))(request)
  }

  def IsOwnerOfTestrun(id: String)(f: Testrun => AuthenticatedData => 
        Request[AnyContent] => Result) = 
    IsAuthenticated { authenticatedData => implicit request => {
      // auth code
      f(testrun)(authenticatedData)(request)
  }
}
```

How could I mock these methods in the Secured trait?

I am using Play 2.1.1 / Scala 2.10.0 with ScalaMock 3.0.1 with Specs2:

```
"org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-specs2-support" % "3.0.1" % "test"
```

Comment: Have you tried to mock it and experienced problems? If so, what problems? Mocking a method that takes a function parameter should be no different from mocking any other method. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I tried it but I got compilation errors. Can you provide an example how to mock methods that are taking a function parameter?

Comment: Hi Markus, did you get a working solution?

Comment: No, I switched to Mockito.